# a generic function to find height for label by passing the string that the label is to be populated

Tags: iphone

i need to find height for a label with certain text based on its font and length.
It requires to be generic to hold font as well as a parameter.

Answer (score 4):

To get the height of a `NSString` object using  `sizeWithFont:` method.

```
NSString *theText = myLabel.text;
CGFloat width = myLabel.frame.size.width ;
CGSize theSize = [theText sizeWithFont:myLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSize(width,MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Here is the height of your `UILabel` .

```
CGFloat myLabelHeight = theSize.height;
```

Comment: Wow! Thats a really short code to serve the purpose! Thanks a lot! Sorry for the late reply!

Comment: @Teddy: glad it help u ...accept the answer only if it serve your purpose.

Comment: To be correct, this line:

`CGSize theSize = [theText sizeWithFont:myLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSize(width,MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];`

Should be:

`CGSize theSize = [theText sizeWithFont:myLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width,MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];`

Comment: Guys Thanks a lot! Yes i accept the answer very much. Sorry i dint see this page since long...